# Increasing the performance for a Numpy function with Numba Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, function, numba

I am trying to speed up one of my functions using the `numba` library however it gives me the error down below. The standard deviation function should be able to run with the numba's `@njit` function. The standard deviation functions purpose is also stated in this post: [standard deviation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLnUx.png)

Variables

```
from numba import njit,jit,vectorize
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
number = 10
PC_list = np.array([52599, 52575, 53598, 336368, 336875, 337466, 338292, 356587, 357474, 357763, 358491, 358659, 359041, 360179, 360286])
```

Pandas function

```
std= pd.Series(PC_list).rolling(number).std().dropna().to_numpy()
```

Numba Acceleration

```
@njit
def std():
    std= pd.Series(PC_list).rolling(number).std().dropna().to_numpy()
    return std
STD_order = std()
```

Error Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

C:\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py in _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    412                 e.patch_message(msg)
    413 
--> 414             error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    415         except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    416             # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info

C:\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py in error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    355                 raise e
    356             else:
--> 357                 raise e.with_traceback(None)
    358 
    359         argtypes = []

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'Series' of type Module(<module 'pandas' from 'C:\\Python3.7\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\__init__.py'>)

File "<timed exec>", line 3:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>

During: typing of get attribute at <timed exec> (3)

File "<timed exec>", line 3:
```

Time Difference between Numba and the Panda's Function:
[image]

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney right I will fix that and update the question

Comment: `%%time` should not be in cell 21, it should be in the cell where you call the function. So in a new cell `%%time` and then `std()` Also, it doesn't like that it's a pandas series. the functions I tested were numpy arrays.

Comment: Its uses a pandas function to compute and then it turns the already computed function into numpy form.

Comment: [pandas User Guide: numba](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#using-numba) I didn't test your function specificlaly, but it must be formatted a specific way, per the guide.

Comment: AFAIK `numba` does not support `pandas` data structures. Even if it did, it wouldn't make a lot of sense to try to JIT something like `pd.Series(PC_list).rolling(number).std().dropna()` which just calls a bunch of pandas methods, numba JIT is effective for JIT compiling highly procedural, non-vectorized code like you might write when working with Python lists but applied to `numpy.ndarray`'s. e.g. for-loops, etc

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Oh I see, Is there a way I could accelerate the `std= pd.Series(PC_list).rolling(number).std().dropna().to_numpy()` function by any chance. Like maybe plitting the `PC_list` into chunks and such. I am trying to optimize the function.

Comment: Yes, as @juanpa.arrivillaga has pointed out, the guide shows the pandas columns being converted to numpy arrays.

Comment: @tonyselcuk You could try implementing the logic yourself in a `numba.jit` function, although, `pandas` is pretty highly tuned if you want to work with pandas data structures... but it may be faster if you implement it with pure numpy arrays with numba. Not sure exactly what you are proposing about splitting it into chunks...'

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I meant to say maybe if I could split the `PC_list` into multiple chunks using `np.split` or something like that maybe that would decrease the runtime.  I will try implementing the `numba.jit` function too.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga @TrentonMcKinney  the `numba.jit` doesnt really work but thanks for the help.

Comment: Although i havent tried it, you might wanna take a look at Intel's `sdc` project : https://github.com/IntelPython/sdc